# Can you use Oculus controllers in a blender scene?

Tags: vr, oculus

I've made a simple scene in blender where I have orbs that you can look at using an Oculus Quest. I've managed to get that to work, however I was wondering if you can use the Oculus controllers in a way that you can interact with objects.

Answer (score 1):

There is an official addon [VR Inspection](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/addons/3d_view/vr_scene_inspection.html) shipped by default with Blender that allows basic interaction with a scene using a supported Virtual Reality device using the open library [OpenXR](https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Source/Interface/XR).

You can activate it by going to *Edit > Preferences > Addons > 3D View: VR Scene Inspection*. You can then interact with it from the 3D View Sidebar ( <kbd>N</kbd> Panel), *VR* tab.

[image]

Beware that this is not a full featured editing interface, nor a replacement for traditional input methods, rather a consumption tool for visualization purposes and interactive real time scene inspection.